# Only updating image if something else is updated, not if only updating image

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to update an item that could have an image or change the one that is already there, when I only change the image or add one it doesn't update, but if I change or add an image along with something else like the name or description then it does update both things. I'm not sure why this is happening.

I'm sending it to the controller like this

```
submit(item) {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.imagen);
    data.append('name', this.ruleForm.name);
    data.append('summary', this.ruleForm.summary);
    data.append('description', this.ruleForm.description);
    data.append('price', this.ruleForm.price);
    data.append('hours', this.ruleForm.hours);
    data.append('min_grade', this.ruleForm.min_grade);
    data.append('matery', this.matery);
    data.append('remover', this.remover);
    data.append('strict', this.strict);

    this.$refs.ruleForm.validate((valid) => {
        if (valid) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.$inertia.post('/courses/' + item.id, data)
                .then(
                    () => {
                        this.$message({
                            type: 'success',
                            message: 'Guardado correctamente.'
                        });
                        this.loading = false
                    },
                    (res) => {
                        this.$message.error(parseError(res)[0]);
                        this.loading = false;
                    })
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
},
```

This is the full update function in the controller

```
public function update(CourseSaveRequest $request, $id)
{
    Log::info($request);
    $editCourse = Course::find($id);

    $editCourse->name = $request->name;
    $editCourse->summary = $request->summary;
    $editCourse->description = $request->description;
    $editCourse->price = $request->price;
    $editCourse->hours = $request->hours;
    $editCourse->min_grade = $request->min_grade;

    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $this->removeImage($editCourse);
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $imageName = Uuid::generate(4)->string . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $editCourse->image = '/' . 'img/courses' . '/' . $imageName;
        $request->file('file')->move('img/courses', $imageName);
    }

    $editCourse->save();

    return back();
}

private function removeImage(Course $course){
    if (!empty($course->image) && file_exists(public_path($course->image))) {
        unlink(public_path($course->image));
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is relevant but this is the CourseSaveRequest

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|unique:courses',
        'summary' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'hours' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'min_grade' => 'required|numeric|min:0'
    ];

    if ($this->has('id')) {
        $rules['name'] .= ',id,'.$this->get('id');
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: I suspect it's the unique rule on the name attribute, if the name doesn't change then I believe that rule will fail. You can change the rule to ignore the current model instance for updates `Rule::unique('name')->ignore($course->id)`

Comment: @AlecJoy where would I put that? In the request?

Comment: Yes, check my answer. Code snippet was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's the unique rule on the name, you can ignore the current model instance on unique with the following

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
...
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'name' => [
            'required', 
            Rule::unique('courses')->ignore($this->id)
        ],
        'summary' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'hours' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'min_grade' => 'required|numeric|min:0'
    ];

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: $courses or $course? It should be course, singular.

Comment: Okay, might be a model binding problem, try changing $course->id to `$this->get('id')`

Comment: now I'm getting this exception: ```SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'inae.name' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `name` where `name` = Principiante Clase 6 (automático))``` on where it says `Rule::unique('name')`

Comment: oh jeez, sorry, I was typing too fast. It should be Rule::unique('courses'), I'll update the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204357/discussion-between-nancy-and-alec-joy).